# Invalid object name "django_migrations" when trying to runserver

Tags: python, sql-server, django, odbc

I wanted to connect my Django app to client's MSSQL database (Previously my app worked on SQLite). I made an migration on their test server and It worked successfully, then they copied this database to destination server and when I try to

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It shows me just

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_migrations'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

What can be possible problem with this? This is my connection:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
       'NAME': 'ESD',
       'HOST': 'IPaddress',
       'USER': 'Username',
       'PASSWORD': 'Password',

       'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
        }
   }
}
```

I tried to migrate too, it shows me the same error

There are all errors:

```
(norm)esd@server:~/Desktop/norm/myproject> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fc57eb4f8c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 66, in applied_migrations
    return set(tuple(x) for x in self.migration_qs.values_list("app", "name"))
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 128, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 802, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/esd/Desktop/norm/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 537, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_migrations'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: You  did not migrate apparently.

Comment: I tried to python manage.py migrate, but it also shows same error

Comment: Please post all stack trace errors.

Comment: @MateoSkyline were you ever able to solve this issue?

Comment: @MarthinusBosman were you ever able to solve this issue?

Comment: Posted [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74474083/1748046)

Answer (score 1):

So the reason this is happening is likely because the **default schema you've set for django's internal tables isn't the same as the default schema of your current user**.

You can test this by checking the actual schema of `django_migrations` table in your database, and then run a python script to verify your current default schema, like below:

```py
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

db_host = "Your host URL"
db_name = "Your DB name"

engine = db.create_engine(
    f"mssql+pyodbc://@{db_host}/{db_name}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0"
)

statement = text("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME();")

with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        results = connection.execute(statement)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

If they're not the same, go in to SQL Server Manager and set the default schema for your user to the correct one.

To see what user your connected as, just replace `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()` with `SELECT SYSTEM_USER` and run again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to run `"py manage.py makemigrations"` first and then `"py manage.py migrate".`

If not, maybe it's worth adding the specific host and port for the databases. What I used for my project that uses mysql were the following.

```
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
>         'NAME': 'pkg',
>         'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
>         'PORT': '3306',
>         'USER': 'root',
>         'PASSWD': '',
>     } }
```

Not sure if it will work but perhaps it's worth trying.

Comment: Unfortunately, makemigrations do nothing :(

Comment: What do you mean it does nothing? What is the message after you run makemigrations?

Comment: Same error seems to me.
After makemigrations is done, it shows the below error.

('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'accounts_studentprofile'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

I have entered the email and password for login. But it gets error to go to the profile page.